# Split a column into 3 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have table 1 like this:

```
----------------
|  id  |  col  |
----------------
|   1  |   7   |
|   2  |   6   |
|   3  |   1   |
|   4  |   8   |
|   5  |   9   |
|   6  |   5   |
|   7  |   4   |
|   8  |   3   |
|   9  |   2   |
----------------
```

I want to create new table get data from column `col` of table 1 and get the result like this:

```
-------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------
|  7  |  6  |  1  |
|  8  |  9  |  5  |
|  4  |  3  |  2  |
-------------------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Not sure what you're asking.** (And there's a possibility that your question will be put on hold for that reason). When you say *new table* do you mean a table with three `INTEGER` fields named `A`, `B` and `C`? Are you asking that for the first record, column `A` should contain the `col` for `id` 1, `B` should contain the `col` for `id` 2, etc?

Comment: @BobKaufman yes, I mean new table with three INTEGER fields named A, B, C; and in new table, first row consist of the first 3 rows of table 1, second row consist of the next 3 rows of table1, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Assuming the ID is incremental**

```
Declare @Table table (id int,col int)
Insert Into @Table values
(1,7),
(2,6),
(3,1),
(4,8),
(5,9),
(6,5),
(7,4),
(8,3),
(9,2)


Select ColA=max(case when ID % 3 = 1 then col else 0 end)
      ,ColB=max(case when ID % 3 = 2 then col else 0 end)
      ,ColC=max(case when ID % 3 = 0 then col else 0 end)
 From @Table
 Group By ceiling(ID/3.0)
```

Returns

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
7       6       1
8       9       5
4       3       2
```